# Identifying and handling more than one dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand in principle how Python "thinks". Maybe someone can explain and inlighten me:

If I read two data sets into one pandas dataframe each, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
```

How does Python know which one of the two dataframes I want to actually use?

How does the internal mapping work?

I am able to call the both dataframes with `df1` and `df2` and do calculations or chose subsets of them but I am not able to do something like
`print(df1.name)` as no name is explicitly given. Why?

Can I access somehow the identifyer ('df1' or 'df2') of the dataframes like a string variable? How does Python establish the link between my call and the correct memory location?

Or can I pass the identifyer to a string variable **without** explicitly assigning a name to the two dataframes with

```
df1.name = 'df1'
```

and

```
df2.name = 'df2'
```

?

Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: The objects are unaware of the names that bind to them. Actually there can be more than one name per object, or even none (temporarily as least). If you need to keep track of an identifier, use a dictionary.